# Полный путь к файлу linux в программе С++

Tags: c++, linux, файлы, файловая-система, fstream

Хочу написать программу, которая создаст мне файл не в папке самой программы, а в заданой мной директории линукс, например, ~/workspace/file.txt. Я задаю полный путь, компилирую программу, выполняю, но файл ею не создается. Что я делаю не так?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

    int main()
    {
        const char *path="/workspace/file.txt";
        std::ofstream file(path);
        std::string data("data to write to file");
        file << data;
        file.close();

    }
```

Comment: `/workspace` и `~/workspace` — это совершенно разные каталоги. первого, скорее всего, вообще не существует.

Comment: @alexander barakin, заменил часть строки `/workspace` на `~/workspace`. Результат программы тот же.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего, у программы нет прав на запись в данную директорию. Для проверки выполните `#chmod 777 /workspace` и `#setenforce 0`

И попробуйте выполнить вот такой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

    int main()
    {
        std::ofstream tmpfile("/workspace/tempfile.txt");
        std::string mystring("data to write to file");
        tmpfile << mystring << std::endl;
        tmpfile.close();

    }
```

Код точно рабочий - проверил на своей виртуалке:

```
[root@svm]# rm -rf /workspace/*
[root@svm]# cat output.c
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

    int main()
    {
        std::ofstream tmpfile("/workspace/tempfile.txt");
        std::string mystring("data to write to file");
        tmpfile << mystring << std::endl;
        tmpfile.close();

    }
[root@svm]# g++ output.c -o myprog
[root@svm]# ll /workspace/
total 0
[root@svm]# ./myprog
[root@svm]# ll /workspace/
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 22 Oct 19 20:56 tempfile.txt
[root@svm]# cat /workspace/tempfile.txt
data to write to file
[root@svm]#
```

Comment: `#chmod 777 /workspace `ничего не дало. 
#setenforce 0 выдает `setenforce: SELinux is disabled`

Comment: Кстати, а разве не нужно делать include iostream?

Comment: зачем здесть #include iostream?

Comment: Добавил код в ответ. Попробуйте выполнить его.

Comment: безрезультатно. Возможна ли какая то проблема у меня в самой системе?

Comment: Сейчас я развернул linux-виртуалку и ставлю devel tools. Проверю код локально на линуксовой машине и отпишусь Вам. Я по прежнему считаю что дело в правах доступа.

Comment: я пробовал менят директорию на любые другие. Результат был тот же.

Comment: я так же пробовал запускать програму с правами суперпользователя.  
`g++ vardir.cpp -o dir
 sudo ./dir`
ничего не помогло

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, вывод команды `ls -lh / | grep works` А также `cat vardir.cpp`

Comment: `vovanrew@comp:~/workspace$ ls -lh / | grep works
vovanrew@comp:~/workspace$`
ничего не выводит

Comment: Может перейдём в чат? Или дайте Ваш скайп - я проконсультирую.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47083/discussion-between-vova-polischuck-and-alexandr-blinov).

Comment: давайте в скайпе. wowka97000

Comment: или в чат зайдите. Вот ссылка выше